# What happened to VSFileFinder.Connect.ShowVSFileFinder in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I wanted to mimic the functionality in Eclipse where you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open a file, [I read that this is possible](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/mimic-the-eclipse-open-resource-feature-in-visual-studio/) but when I opened my own Visual Studio 2010 instance, I noticed that it was not contained in the Show Commands Containing search of the Keyboard options menu.

Has the name of this functionality changed in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Anybody have an answer to this one yet?  (our project is rather huge and it would be a big help!)

Comment: So they got rid of this in VS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Sonic File Finder which does the same thing:

http://www.jens-schaller.de/sonictools/sonicfilefinder/index.htm